# Phusion Passenger processes show very different memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Here's the output of `passenger-status` from production:

```
  * PID: 24388   Sessions: 0       Processed: 103069   Uptime: 2d 22h 47m 44s
    CPU: 3%      Memory  : 1376M   Last used: 19s
  * PID: 2380    Sessions: 0       Processed: 2844    Uptime: 21h 6m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 575M    Last used: 1m 4s ag
  * PID: 4192    Sessions: 0       Processed: 44      Uptime: 5h 59m 21s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 315M    Last used: 7m 40s a
```

Notice the difference in memory consumption of the three processes. Is this normal? Or does this mean that my application is leaking memory, and therefore, the memory usage is correlated with the number of requests served by each process (which is expected to be "lopsided" as explained in the [docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/request_load_balancing.html#traffic-may-appear-unbalanced-between-processes))?

PS: This is a Ruby on Rails app, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Is this normal? Yes.

Passenger will balance the load of requests across the instances in precedential order of there "freedom". In your case (as it is for most) the first instance serves the most requests because it has the highest precedence. If instance 1 is busy then passenger will try instance 2, then instance 3 and so on.

Does this mean my application is leaking memory? I do not have insight into your code base but the most likely answer in this context is no.

The instance of the application will continue to grow (to a point) based on the Objects loaded into memory. Rails uses auto loading so that it does not load Objects until their first use (depending on config). Constants like (classes, modules, global variables, etc) will stick around forever in your application memory and other objects will be garbage collected (sooner or later) along the way. This combination is likely what you are seeing.

Comment: In production mode, Rails pre-loads most of the classes and constants, right? Why would there be 2-4x difference in passenger instances that are being used frequently, and aren't?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda not all Objects are constants and not all Objects get GC'd. Many objects are ephemeral (when the GC comes around which isn't as deterministic as you might think) but others like Symbols are interned. Again I don't know your code base but for the sake of an example `100.times{Class.new}` creates 100 anonymous classes but this wouldn't be auto loaded by rails if it was contained inside a method call. This would only occur upon invocation.